# Omit border of a variation table using the tkz-tab package

Tags: tables, border, function, tkz-tab

Is there a way to omit the border lines in a sign and variation table of a function in the tkz-tab package?

[image]

My Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{h style/.style = {fill=red!50}}    
\tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=2]{$x$ /1, $f(x)$ /2}{$-4$,$1$,$4$,$5$}% 
\tkzTabVar{-/ $\stackrel{min}{-3}$ / , +/ $\stackrel{max}{4}$ / , -/ $1$, -/ $1$ / }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: this way -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537535/197451 -- or better with --- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394888/197451

Comment: The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-tab/doc/TKZdoc-tab.pdf) suggests to use the `nocadre` option: `\tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=2,nocadre]...`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-tab/doc/TKZdoc-tab.pdf) suggests to use the `nocadre` option:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{h style/.style = {fill=red!50}}    
\tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=2,nocadre]{$x$ /1, $f(x)$ /2}{$-4$,$1$,$4$,$5$}% 
\tkzTabVar{-/ $\stackrel{min}{-3}$ / , +/ $\stackrel{max}{4}$ / , -/ $1$, -/ $1$ / }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]